# Firebase Polymer authentication exception

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebasesimplelogin

I'm trying to get the Firebase authentication/sync running in the ["Topeka" Polymer-sample](https://github.com/Polymer/topeka/).

This is what I've done:

1. Checked out `topeka-master` from GitHub
2. Ran `bower install`
3. Created a new Firebase-account and added the FirebaseIO-URL of the newly created project to topeka-datasource.html and topeka-leaderboard.html
4. Enabled anonymous auth in the Firebase project

Everything works fine if I use the `.../?test`-flag (which doesn't use Firebase)

Without the flag, I'm getting the following exceptions in Firefox (33.0.3):

```
Exception caught during observer callback: .locationChanged@data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8,%0A%20%20%0A%20%20Polymer('firebase-login'%2C%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Fired%20when%20user%20is%20logged%20in%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%40event%20login%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Fired%20when%20user%20is%20logged%20out%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%40event%20logout%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Fired%20when%20an%20error%20occurred%20logging%20in%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%40event%20error%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Fired%20when%20user%20is%20created%20(password%20provider%20type)%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%40event%20user-created%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Fired%20when%20user%20changes%20their%20password%20(password%20provider%20type)%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2"[…] observe.js:753

TypeError: this.ref.onAuth is not a function data:%0A%20%20%0A%20%20Polymer('firebase-login'%2C%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Fired%20when%20user%20is%20logged%20in%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%40event%20login%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Fired%20when%20user%20is%20logged%20out%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%40event%20logout%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Fired%20when%20an%2[...]components%2Ffirebase-element%2Ffirebase-login.html.js%0A:142
```

And in Chrome (40.0.2209.0 dev-m):

```
 Exception caught during observer callback: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at firebase-login.Polymer.locationChanged (http://www.sample.com/mysubdir/components/firebase-element/firebase-login.html:164:18)
    at firebase-login.properties.invokeMethod (http://www.sample.com/mysubdir/components/polymer/src/instance/properties.js:114:12)
    at firebase-login.properties.notifyPropertyChanges (http://www.sample.com/mysubdir/components/polymer/src/instance/properties.js:103:20)
    at Object.Observer.report_ (http://www.sample.com/mysubdir/components/observe-js/src/observe.js:750:24)
    at Object.createObject.check_ (http://www.sample.com/mysubdir/components/observe-js/src/observe.js:1156:12)
    at callback (http://www.sample.com/mysubdir/components/observe-js/src/observe.js:648:20)
```

Comment: Can you please include version info and some code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Kato. Which versions would you like to know? I've pulled the current stable versions of all dependencies (e.g. polymer, firebase-element, firebase, firebase-simple-login) automatically using bower. The exception references multiple files, but I guess the one ultimately causing the exception is: https://github.com/Polymer/firebase-element/blob/master/firebase-login.html#L164